# How to change name of form in php when its in while loop?

Tags: php, forms, while-loop

```
    $friendRequests = ("SELECT * FROM zahtjevi_prijatelja WHERE user_to='".$_SESSION['ID']."'");
    $res = mysql_query($friendRequests) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) ==0) {
     echo "You have no friend Requests at this time.";
     $user_from = "";
    }
    else
    {


     while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
```

> While return all friend requests ,and create form for every request. Form is in while-loop.
>   What i want to do is that if I press submit button for one of requests that i get, add only for pressed to database, but in my case all requests are added. Its because form name is always the same in while-loop so i need some how dynamically change name of form if there is more friend requests.

```
      <form action="friendRequest.php" method="post" id="myForm"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">



    <input type="submit" name="acceptrequest" value="Accept Request">
    <input type="submit" name="ignorerequest" value="Ignore Request"><br>


    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not overthinking your implementation logic? as a simple table with radio buttons & a button at the bottom would be a cost/time effective implementation

Comment: You want to send accept or reject to only one person isn't it? @Emil Balint

Comment: Yes,that's correct.@MuhammadAshikuzzaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a multiselect dropdown to accept multiple requests or a single one at a time?

```
<form>
<label for="accept_request"
<select multiple name="accept_request[]">
  <option value="1">Friend Request 1</option>
  <option value="2">Friend Request 2</option>
  <option value="3">Friend Request 3</option>
  <option value="4">Friend Request 4</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: Tnx, idea with select worked,now i can add them one by one. Thank U once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this: Will work better.

```
 <form action="friendRequest.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID'].'acceptrequest'; ?>" value="Accept Request">
    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID'].'ignorerequest'? " value="Ignore Request"><br>

 </form>
```

In friendRequest.php use this:

```
 $a=$_SESSION['ID'].'acceptrequest'; 
 $b=$_SESSION['ID'].'ignorerequest';
 if(isset($_POST[$a]))
    {
    ..................... 
    }
if(isset($_POST[$b]))
    {
    ..................... 
    }
```